How to remove attachments from a draft email using Microsoft Graph API in C#?
I'm trying to remove attachments from a draft email when forwarding it using the Microsoft Graph API in a C# application. However, I'm encountering a "tooManyRetries" error when trying to delete the attachments.
Here is the relevant code:
private static async Task<Message> GetDraftMessageAsync(GraphServiceClient client, EmailCreateServiceModel model,
                                                       ComposeMode mode, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //other modes

    var message = await client.Users[model.OriginalEmailAddress]
        .Messages[model.MessageId]
        .CreateForward()
        .Request()
        .Header("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"")
        .PostAsync(cancellationToken)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Question 1: can I somehow get the draft message with attachments without this second call?
    var messageWithAttachments = await client.Users[model.OriginalEmailAddress]
        .Messages[message.Id]
        .Request()
        .Expand(m => m.Attachments)
        .GetAsync(cancellationToken)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    return messageWithAttachments;
}

public static async Task<Message> SendEmailAsync(EmailCreateServiceModel model, ComposeMode mode, List<string> keepingAttachments,
                                                  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var client = await AuthService.GetGraphClientAsync();
    var draftMessage = await GetDraftMessageAsync(client, model, mode, cancellationToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (mode is ComposeMode.Forward && draftMessage.Attachments != null)
    {
        var attachmentsToRemove = draftMessage.Attachments
            .Where(attachment => !keepingAttachments.Contains(attachment.Name))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var attachment in attachmentsToRemove)
        {
            // Question 2: This code hangs for a long time and then throws the exception
            await client.Users[model.OriginalEmailAddress]
                .Messages[draftMessage.Id]
                .Attachments[attachment.Id]
                .Request()
                .DeleteAsync(cancellationToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    draftMessage.From = string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.From)
        ? null
        : new() { EmailAddress = new() { Address = model.From } };
    draftMessage.ToRecipients = GetRecipients(model.To);
    draftMessage.CcRecipients = GetRecipients(model.Cc);
    draftMessage.BccRecipients = GetRecipients(model.Bcc);
    draftMessage.Subject = model.Subject;
    draftMessage.Body = new ItemBody() { Content = model.Body, ContentType = BodyType.Html, };

    draftMessage = await client.Users[model.OriginalEmailAddress]
            .Messages[draftMessage.Id]
            .Request()
            .UpdateAsync(draftMessage, cancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
}

Problem:

Can I somehow get the draft message with attachments without making
a second call?
The code (from the part shown) hangs for a long time and then throws an
exception when trying to delete attachments from the draft message.

Error Details:
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Code: tooManyRetries
  Message: More than 3 retries encountered while sending the request.

  Source=Microsoft.Graph.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendRequestAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   ...
   at Microsoft.Graph.AttachmentRequest.<DeleteAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in AttachmentRequest.cs
   ...

Questions:

Is there a specific permission required to delete attachments from a draft message?
Is there an issue with how I'm fetching and modifying the draft message?
How can I handle the "tooManyRetries" error properly?
Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
Using graph explorer I'm getting this error:


Hi, could you pls help confirm whether you could call this API successfully then let's troubleshoot it codes? Here's the API document and this is the URL: /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/attachments/{id}. In the right corner of this page, there's a Open Graph Explorer button and we could sign in and test API there.

One alternate method of doing it would be to grab the Mime content of the original message then use something like mimekit https://mimekit.net/docs/html/Working-With-Messages.htm to build the response locally and then send the forward message using the mime you built client side. That saves you having to make multiple calls to the Graph, but to debug why your getting too many retries you need to know the underlying error your getting that's causing the retry (eg 501, 429) etc.

@TinyWang On the graph explorer, the same URL with the GET method works just fine. When I run it with DELETE method, it goes on for a while and then gives me the error Mailbox move in progress. Try again later.

Are you able to delete at least one attachment?

Maybe it's related to this issue.
